# Passwordless single sign on using SFSafariViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller, password-less, safariservices

I integrate with `safariService` (`SFSafariViewController`) to log in through a single sign-on password, the problem was the first time I log in using `SFSafariViewController` the authentication does not complete the first time so the Safari browser still appears & can not direct into my app after authentication follow to become a success.

Another odd behavior is when I login again the authentication follow work fine & get the token then directed into my app fine so the main problem is the first time I login `SFSafariViewController` does not catch the user auth.

```
   if let url = URL(string: "url") {
        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        safariVC.delegate = self

        safariVC.dismissButtonStyle = .done
        present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
extension DouWebViewVC: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, didCompleteInitialLoad didLoadSuccessfully: Bool) {
    if didLoadSuccessfully {
            print("didLoadSuccessfully")
            // Do something with the URL here
    }
}

//initialLoadDidRedirectTo
func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, initialLoadDidRedirectTo requestUrl: URL) {
    let absoluteUrl = requestUrl.absoluteString
    print("requestUrl\(requestUrl)")
}

func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
    print("safariViewControllerDidFinish")
}
```

}